# How to share selenium project to others?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have prepared one selenium framework for the Website and it's working fine in my local system. But I want to share this project to my others without share the source-code.
Is this possible to share any executive file and they can run that file?. If yes then how to share and which file to share?.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What libraries are you used to create your selenium project?

Comment: did you try pkg npm module , unless you show your project structure and tell how you execute script. is it a single file project or uses any test frameworks?. It is not possible to answer without these details

Comment: I am using the Maven project with Page Object Module and using TestNG.xml file